# define static string variable in c++ class

Tags: c++, string, static

I have 2 questions:

Why is this possible for an int variable:

### foo.h:

```
class foo{

     private:
        const static int a = 42;
};
```

but for a string variable I need to do it this way?

### foo.h:

```
class foo{

     private:
        static string fooString;
};
```

### foo.cpp:

```
string foo::fooString = "foo";
```

---

And also:

In my particular case foo::fooString should represent a path variable, and I would like that for every object of class foo there were just one instance of foo::string, representing a const value that should never change.

Is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is this possible for an int variable: [..] but for a string variable I need to do it this way?

Just because. Actually you can still make the `string` `const` but, yes, you have to *define* it outside of the class definition. You can only do in-place initialisation of `static` members when they are `const` and integral (or "of literal type").

(In C++11 you can even do it for non-`static` non-`const` members when they are of literal type.)

> I would like that for every object of class foo there were just one instance of foo::string, representing a const value that should never change. Is there another way to solve this problem?

A `static const std::string`, as you might expect.

```
// C++03
struct T {
   static const std::string foo;
};

const std::string T::foo = "lol";
```